# How was this integral split into three parts?

Tags: integration

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\dfrac d{dk}F(k)&=&\dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(-ix)e^{-ikx-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \\
&=&\dfrac i{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty(-x)e^{-ikx-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx-\int_{-\infty}^\infty ik\sigma^2e^{-ikx-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx\\\hspace{6.5cm}+\int_{-\infty}^\infty ik\sigma^2e^{-ikx-\tfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx\right]
\end{array}$$

I am dazzled, since I think the second part can't be partial integration...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't, it's in the form $x=x-a+a$. You subtracted something and added it back. It simplifies the next stage of calculation, as you can group them and introduce a new variable in the first two terms (you constructed the prefactor to be the derivative of the exponent).